# Why am I not able to follow the next page link using scrappy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Okay well I know why because nothing is being extracted for the next_page variable but Im not sure if im using xpath correctly

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http.request import Request


class SunBizSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'sunbiz'
start_urls = ['http://search.sunbiz.org/Inquiry/CorporationSearch/SearchResults?inquiryType=EntityName&searchNameOrder=A&searchTerm=a']

def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.css('.large-width a::attr(href)'):
        full_url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_question)



def parse_question(self, response):
    re1='((?:[0]?[1-9]|[1][012])[-:\\/.](?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1}))[-:\\/.](?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3})))(?![\\d])' # MMDDYYYY 1
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    date = response.xpath('//span').re_first(re1)
    next_page = hxs.select("//div[@class='navigationBar']/@href").extract()
    yield {
        'Name': response.css('.corporationName span::text').extract()[1],
        'Date': date,
        'Link': response.url,
        }
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page[1], callback=self.parse_question)
```

Comment: [link](http://sunbiz.org) is the main site, basically trying to crawl all the businesses and get basic information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you don't need `HtmlXPathSelector` if you are already using `response` as a selector. `response` can handle css and xpath, so don't worry about it.

Second, you are trying to get a link with this xpath `"//div[@class='navigationBar']/@href"`, which says *get the `href` attribute from a div*, which you should agree that is incorrect, `href` attributes come on `<a>` tags, so in this case the xpath you should use is:

```
"//div[@class='navigationBar'][1]//a[@title='Next On List']/@href"
```

Comment: Ahh and yeah I agree i knew that was wrong but i didnt know the correct way to find the link Im trying it now I'll let you know!

Comment: works thabks i knew it was a simple fix just couidn't wrap my mind around it.